# Read multiple file in C++ with the same fstream object

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I use C++ code like below to handle two different file,and it seem that I failed two read the later, is there any limit for a fstream object two read multiple files?

```
fstream fin("file1.txt");
//operation
fin.close();
fin.open("file2.txt");//failed
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to reassociate a file stream with a file. It might be failing for a number of reasons: Does the file exist? You have permissions to open it?

Comment: Can you try specifying just `std::ios::in` instead of leaving it as default which is `std::ios::in | std::ios::out`? I ask because gcc 4.8.1 & 4.9.X fails for me when both are specified :S  Try specifying one and see if it works?

Comment: @Brandon It fails because `std::ios_base::in` prevents the creation of a file if one doesn't exist. Replacing it with `std::ios_base::out` will fix that but you will lose input functionality. It would be better to append `std::ios_base::trunc` to the openmode instead.

Comment: yes, if I switch the argument like file2.txt comes first,file1.txt would be inaccessible.

Comment: I have tried to add a ios_base::in as an argument but also failed.I solve this problem by using two fstream objects.Just wanna know whether one can finish it using only one....

Comment: How do you know opening the second file failed? What error check did you make?

Comment: Yes, it can be solved with one or multiple file streams.

Comment: afaik before C++11 your streams didn't ensure to reset the internal flags to `goodbit` in `open`, those required a `clear` before reopening... whats the standard you're compiling with?

Comment: Oh yes, I add a clear() statement after the close operation, and It work! Thank you so much.【I use g++ 3.4.2】

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After closing a file, you have to call .clear() method before opening a new file with the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

   const char* const files[] = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
   size_t sz = sizeof(files) / sizeof(files[0]);
   std::fstream fin;
   for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
      fin.open(files[i], std::ios_base::out);
      // do something
      fin << "123\n";
      fin.close();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still failed with this method.

Comment: @郑穗展 In what way does it fail?  What happens? Do you have permissions to directory?

Comment: Yes,cuz if I switch the two argument's order, file1.txt would be unable to open,I use if(!fin) to know that it failed.

Comment: @郑穗展 You didn't use the code exactly as above.  If you did, you wouldn't have experienced that problem.